# Incoming call doesn't stop the music in Nexus 5X

Tags: calls, music, music-player

Before this time I've been using Samsung Android-phone with Android 4.4. There was the next feature: when I listen to the music in headphones and somebody calls me then music stops and I start to hear incoming call in my headphones.

Now I moved to Nexus 5X and Android 7 and things were changed. Now when there is incoming call music doesn't stop while phone is vibrating, but I can't feel when I'm walking on the street, so I miss a call.

I've tried to find a solution in settings but without any result. I thought that the problem can be solved by turning off silent mode but it didn't help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happened to me too, but only when Ring Volume is zero (When you put it in vibrate)

I searched for solutions but dint find any, so I have a workaround for this.

Never set your Ring volume to zero, keep it at minimum not zero. Now it'll ring when you get a call stopping your music.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but that is really workaround, and it works. But what if I want to keep notifications even in vibrate mode?

Comment: As i said above, I searched for solutions and did not find any. Hope they fix it in the next version of Android